# Delegate function not being called iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am trying to pass value from one class `LanguageSelectionTVC` to another `RegistrationVC` by using a Protocol.

When I try and call the method `self.delegate?.setSelectedLangauges(self.languagesSpokenArray)` inside `LanguageSelectionTVC` it doesn't call the method `setSelectedLangauges` inside the class `Registration VC` could someone please suggest where I am going wrong ?

```
protocol LanguageSelectionTVCProtocol {
    func setSelectedLangauges(_ valueSent: [String])
}


class LanguageSelectionTVC: UITableViewController {
    var delegate                    : LanguageSelectionTVCProtocol? = nil

   func saveAndClose() {
        self.delegate?.setSelectedLangauges(self.languagesSpokenArray)
        dismiss()
   }

}


class RegistrationVC:           UIViewController,
                                UITableViewDelegate,
                                UITableViewDataSource,
                                LanguageSelectionTVCProtocol{

    func setSelectedLangauges(_ valueSent: [String]){  
         self.showLanguagesSpoken(valueSent)
    }
}
```

Moving to `LanguageSelectionTVC` from `RegistrationVC` . The below `tableView` method is in my `RegistrationVC`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let row     = indexPath.row
        let section = indexPath.section

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        if section == 4 && row == 0 {
            // The user has clicked on languages spoken cell
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LanguageSelectionTVC", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you are setting the delegate show how you are moving to `LanguageSelectionTVC` from `RegistrationVC`

Comment: You have to **set** the delegate somewhere.

Comment: @NiravD updated my question to show how I am moving to `LanguageSelectionTVC` from `RegistrationVC`

Comment: @user44776 Check my below solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access `LanguageSelectionTVC` from  `preparForSegue` to set `delegate` of it. So `override` the `prepare(for:sender:)` in your `RegistrationVC`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "LanguageSelectionTVC" { 
        let vc = segue.destination as! LanguageSelectionTVC
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: @user44776 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate in RegistrationVC to LanguageSelectionTVC, for example you could set it when performing a segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let targetVC = segue.destination as! LanguageSelectionTVC
    targetVC.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set delegate. can you please see below ready example for pass data between two view controller.

```
import UIKit
protocol SenderViewControllerDelegate 
{
    func messageData(str1:NSString)
}
class tableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource 
{
var delegate: tableViewController?
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate?.messageData(str1: “Hello world”)
}
}
```

receive data in below controller

```
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UIViewController ,SenderViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     let objtableview = tableViewController(nibName: "tableViewController",bundle: nil)
        objtableview.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objtableview, animated: true)
    }
    func messageData(str1:NSString){
        print(str1)
    }
}
```